# Is using callback for component state update from redux saga the right way

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

How to better update the view based on API response. Let's say we have a setup where user should be redirected to dashboard view when successfully logs in and an alert message is displayed for any error on the login screen.

**What I currently use**

I am used to call the action creator to finally hit the endpoint for a response. And based on that response dispatch a relevant success or failure `action` to update my global state which I subscribe in my component using `connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)`.

**Problem**

Let's say I have a `loginSuccess` in my global state and I use that for redirection or error handling in my Login component. For instance, I want to also handle response for a Password Reset screen as well. So I store another information in my global state and use it in relevant component.

**Is that even a problem?**

I have a feeling that it's too much information to store in global state.

**What I read new?**

So I started reading about passing a `callback` to my action creator which handles the response. This way the error handling logic stays local to the component.

**Example**

**Login.js**

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.props.login({
        data, // login payload.
        callback: (response) => this.handleResponse(response)
 })
}

// response handler.
handleResponse = response => {
   this.setState({isError: response.isError});
}

render () {
   /* Use the this.state.isError to determine either to redirect or show error */
}
```

**Actions.js**

```
export const login = payload => ({
  type: ATTEMPT_LOGIN,
  payload
})
```

**saga.js**

```
// login handler in saga.
function* loginAttempt({payload}) {
  const {data, callback} = payload;
  try {
     const resp = yield apiCaller.call(method, url, data, headers); // utitly to fetch data and return a standard response.
     callback(resp);
  }catch(error){
     callback(DEFAULT_ERROR_RESPONSE); // {isError: true, message: 'Something went wrong'}
  }
}
```

**Which one is better?**

Is there any better way to handle this sort of stuff? How do you guys handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "global" state is a design decision that Redux made to have a single store.  It's okay to add as many `loginSuccess` properties as you need to the store.  To keep them organized you use [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) to divide your store into slices.

You are already using Redux and Redux Saga.  You shouldn't have to use a callback for something like your problem.  Let the reducers, sagas, and selectors take care of the flow:

```
function* loginAttempt(payload) {
  try {    
    const response = yield apiCaller.call(method, url, data, headers);
    yield put(LOGIN_SUCCESS, response);
  }catch(error){
    yield put(LOGIN_ERROR, error);
  }
}
```

The default state can be something like:

```
user: null,
loginRequestStatus: {
  inProgress: false,
  error: false,
}
```

The reducer for `ATTEMPT_LOGIN` should set it in progress.  The reducer for `LOGIN_SUCCESS` should set the user.  `LOGIN_ERROR` sets the error.  Make selectors like `selectAuthUser` and `selectIsLoginInProgress` that your components can use.  If you're using a router that can talk to Redux, like [`router5`](https://router5.js.org/), you can even redirect from the Saga.